# a Div disapears while Img is rotating in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm using the basic CSS3 function transform: rotate(360deg) ; on an image which gets an ID. But, on Chrome and Safari, when this image is rotating one of my DIV suddenly disapear.

Here is my code :

```
img#logo_up1:hover{
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg) ; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
-ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 

-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Would you have any idea where it is coming from ?

Comment: Can you add the CSS for the disappearing div?

Comment: We would need to see the code for the disappearing `div` before anyone in the community can help you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen that. I've tried with this: http://jsfiddle.net/xVxnD/
Please add more information of your problem. You can edit the fiddle and reshare.